# Add an icon to a new file type

Tags: file, icons, install4j

I created a java application that encrypt files. The encrypted file has its own extension: ".encrpts". 
Now I need to give an icon for that file type. How can I do this?

Comment: This depends on your OS. AFAIK, installers can take care of that for you.

Comment: I am using install4j to create a installer for my aplication. using that can I do this?

Comment: Read the documentation, and you'll find out.

Answer (score 2):

```
WINDOWS:
```

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.[extension]` default key contains a `REG_SZ` string, that is the name of the next key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[that_string]\DefaultIcon` default key ("@") contains this: `[path_to_icon_file],[zero_based_index]`

Example:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt
     @="MyTextFile"
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyTextFile\DefaultIcon
     @="C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe,2"
```

This way, all .txt files will use the third icon from the Explorer executable.

Answer is refer from [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use a "Create a file association" action. It will open the file with the selected launcher and use the launcher icon by default, although you can specify a different icon with the "Icon file for Windows" property.